# Node mysql loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops

Im currently doing this loop on Node.js using the MySQL package

```
            var room_array;
            var room_array_list = [];
            var room_list = connection.query('SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY id', function(err, result) {

                room_array = result;

                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                {
                    var room_name = result[i].room_name;
                    var room_desc = result[i].room_desc; 
                    var room_creator;
                    var room_owner = connection.query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', result[i].user_id, function(error, user) {

                        room_array_list.push({'name': room_name, 'desc': room_desc, 'owner': user[0].username});
                    });



                }

                console.log(room_array_list);
```

But when I try to log the room_array_list Im just getting an empty array [].

So my question is how should I do this loop process to form an array with the room_name, room_desc and owner values?

Comment: connection.query is asynchronous. I wonder if there's a way to consolidate this in such a way that it's done with a single trip to the db (of course there is.)

Comment: Just do a single DB query with a join across the tables. This will eliminate the need to query in a loop.

Comment: Running asynchronous functions within loops will not work in node because you have no idea (nor could you) when your async call completes. Your array is empty because none of your calls have completed by the time your loop terminates. You might consider reading some articles on how to code using asynchronous functions, such as http://www.nodebeginner.org/#event-driven-callbacks